# How do I create a VDI file with the contents of a folder? (like zipping it)

Tags: virtualbox, 7-zip

I can't just use 7-Zip to add it to an archive. All it does is add a folder with all the stuff in it.

Also, it doesn't seem to work when I do it that way in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

A VDI file is a VirtualBox *disk image*. It contains the content of an entire *hard disk*, not just a folder.

The only way to get files in a .VDI file is to have a Guest with OS, add a new harddisk to that guest, boot into the OS, initialize the disk, create a partition with driveletter, create a folder and then copy the files into it.

Answer (score 0):

As [LPChip says](https://superuser.com/questions/1681318/how-do-i-create-a-vdi-file-with-the-contents-of-a-folder-like-zipping-it/1681330#1681330), a VDI file is a VirtualBox disk image. It contains the content of an entire hard disk, not just a folder. You are probably trying to share files between your host OS and your virtual machine. If you're trying to do that, here is what you need to do:

1. Go to your virtual machine's settings
2. Go to *Shared Folders* and click on the <kbd>Add</kbd> button
3. Now specify *Folder Path* as the location of the folder on the host OS, *Folder Name* as the name by which it will appear in your VM and *Mount path* as their location in your VM
4. Check the options you want to and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Now that folder will be common in both your VM and host, so you can transfer files here and there. Also please ensure that you have installed *Guest additions*. For that, while your VM is up, go to menu *Devices* → insert Guest additions CD image.